# Unexpected Behavior when Parsing Text File

Tags: php, text-processing

I am learning PHP, & right now I'm stuck.
I am reading a .txt file in the script. The file contents are like this:

```
joe:secret
root:admin
```

I can read the file easily using the `file()` function, which returns an array. I store the data in a a variable as:

```
$data = file('location/file.txt');
```

Next I use foreach loop, and then I explode each line, and store its contents in a variable again. Then I put checks on the variable, but this is where I get behavior which I don't understand.

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
  $row = explode(":", $d);

  if ($row[0] == "joe" && $row[1] == "secret") {
    echo "match found ";
  }
}
```

The above code does give expected output. Why is that? If I do this,

```
echo $row[0]; echo $row[1];
```

then I do receive correct output. So I don't get why my check fails?

Comment: Did you say that both of them give correct output?

Comment: @kojow7 Yes I got it why this was happening. You can read the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was tricky; I don't blame you for not catching this :)

So first, let's investigate with the `php -a` interactive shell:

```
php > $data = file('test.txt');
php > var_dump($data);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "joe:secret
"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "root:admin
"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "
"
}
```

See how the closing quote is on a separate line? That's because the `\n`'s at the end of each line are kept inside each array element in `$data`. So `$row[1]` *doesn't* equal `"secret"`; it equals `"secret\n"`. To fix this, all we need is [`rtrim()`](https://secure.php.net/rtrim):

```
foreach ($data as $line) {
  $line = rtrim($line);
  $row = explode(":", $line);

  if ($row[0] == "joe" && $row[1] == "secret") {
    echo "Match found for joe!";
  }
}
```

Now, it works as expected:

```
php > $data = file('test.txt');
php > foreach ($data as $line) {
php {   $line = rtrim($line);
php {   $row = explode(":", $line);
php {
php {   if ($row[0] == "joe" && $row[1] == "secret") {
php {     echo "Match found for joe!";
php {   }
php { }
Match found for joe!
php >
```

**Edit:** We could also use [`file_get_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of `file()`, so we just get the file contents as a string, and convert it into an array ourselves:

```
$data = file_get_contents('test.txt');
foreach (explode("\n", $data) as $line) {
  $row = explode(":", $line);

  if ($row[0] == "joe" && $row[1] == "secret") {
    echo "Match found for joe!";
  }
}
```

Comment: this makes sesne :) thank you for the lovely explanation. The code works now.

Comment: Awesome, no problem, glad to help! :)